# How to get value from property file inside jquery.html() function

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp

```
$("#divid").html($(data).html() + "<input type="checkbox" id="checkplease" onclick="toggleCheckbox(this)"/>  value="<g:message code="property.value" />");
```

I want to get the value of checkbox from property file. How should I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the quotations, try this:

```
$("#divid").html($(data).html() + "<input type='checkbox' id='checkplease' onclick='toggleCheckbox(this)' value=" + "<g:message code='close.button.label'/>" + "/>");
```